# angular material svg icon from a base directory

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am offering a web widget through a CDN, and I am using angular material.
I want to set the "md-svg-src" attribute for the svg icons to use my base directory from my CDN.

I tried to use a custom directive, but angular material doesn't compile the svg icon (it does set the "md-svg-src" attribute though).

I also would like to do it as efficiently as possible and not make angular re-compile if not necessary.

This is my code so far:

```
<!-- md-icon with a relative url -->
    <md-icon my-svg-src="addShoppingCart"
             aria-label="Insert Drive Icon">
    </md-icon>
```

The directive definition:

```
app.directive("mySvgSrc", function ($compile) {

            return {
                compile: function (tElement, attrs) {

                    var baseUrl = "http://localhost/mySrc/New Folder/";
                    attrs.$set("md-svg-src", baseUrl + attrs.mySvgSrc + ".svg");

                }
            }
        })
```

Note: You can't use the angular material svg url with their cdn because of cors issues. You can download an example from: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/img/icons/cake.svg

Thanks for the help.

Here is the full code (u just have to keep an svg file locally, see my note);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">


</head>
<body>

    <!-- md-icon with a relative url -->
    <md-icon my-svg-src="addShoppingCart"
             aria-label="Insert Drive Icon">
    </md-icon>


    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.10 used here -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("main", ["ngMaterial"]);

        app.directive("mySvgSrc", function ($compile) {

            return {
                compile: function (tElement, attrs) {

                    var baseUrl = "http://localhost/mySrc/New Folder/";
                    attrs.$set("md-svg-src", baseUrl + attrs.mySvgSrc + ".svg");

                }
            }
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you create the full url in your controller like `$scope.fullUrl = baseUrl + $scope.addShopingCart + ".svg;"` and then pass it directly into `md-svg-src` attribute

Comment: Because i have many like that in the code, this seems more DRY to me.

Comment: Well then you can create a function in your controller which returns the full url given the name of the icon. This function can then be called in `md-svg-src = "{{functionName('iconName')}}"`. Seems DRY to me.. ;)